# How to create a custom hook to post to an API and store result?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a login form that is using `useState` hook to store inputs' (username and password) state, so I can pass this data to a function using `createAsyncThunk` that posts to an API and stores its result.

Currently here is what I have:

Login.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Avatar,
  Button,
  Checkbox,
  Container,
  CssBaseline,
  FormControlLabel,
  Grid,
  Link,
  TextField,
  Typography,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { useAuth } from '../hooks';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
import { authManager } from '../authManager';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  //...
}));

const Login: React.FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { push } = useHistory();
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleUsername: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) =>
    setUsername(e.target.value);
  const handlePassword: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) =>
    setPassword(e.target.value);

  const SignIn = async () => {
    await useAuth(username, password);
  };

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="E-mail"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            value={username}
            onChange={handleUsername}
            autoFocus
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Senha"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            value={password}
            onChange={handlePassword}
          />
          <Button
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
            onClick={SignIn}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

useAuth.ts (custom hook)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { authOperations } from 'src/features/auth/redux/';
import { getAuth } from 'src/features/auth/redux/authSelector';

export default (username: string, password: string) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const auth = useSelector(getAuth);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      authOperations.getAccessToken({
        username,
        password,
      })
    );
  }, [dispatch, username, password]);

  return {
    auth,
  };
};
```

This is not working, in fact I'm getting the `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` error.

So, how I fire a custom hook method from a button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you call useAuth it will return the function that you want to call later.

E.g., after

```
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
```

you can put

```
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const auth = useAuth();
```

Then you can call auth() in the SignIn function, instead of calling useAuth there.

You may have a few other things to fix after that, but that should get you on the right track.